# Solving this logical puzzle by resolution doesn't work for me

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

In [this document](http://www.csi.ucd.ie/staff/jpms/talks/talksite/jpms-ecai10-tut.pdf) there is a logical puzzle:

> If the unicorn is mythical, then it is immortal. If the unicorn is not mythical, then it is a mortal mammal. If the unicorn is either immortal or a mammal, then it is horned. The unicorn is magical if it is horned.

They go on by defining:

$M: \text{unicorn is mythical}$

$I: \text{unicorn is immortal}$

$L: \text{unicorn is mammal}$

$H : \text{unicorn is horned}$

$G : \text{unicorn is magical}$

Putting the definitions and the text together they get to this formula

$$(M \rightarrow I) \wedge (\neg M \rightarrow (\neg I \wedge L)) \wedge ((I \vee L) \rightarrow H) \wedge (H \rightarrow G) $$

which is the first thing that doesn't make sense to me, since the text says "**either** immortal **or** a mammal". Shouldn't it be an xor instead of $\vee$?

Anyway, they continue by resolving the formula in this way:

\begin{align*}
&(M \rightarrow I) \wedge (\neg M \rightarrow (\neg I \wedge L)) \wedge ((I \vee L) \rightarrow H) \wedge (H \rightarrow G) \\
&(\neg M \vee I) \wedge (M \vee (\neg I \wedge L)) \wedge ((I \vee L) \rightarrow H) \wedge (H \rightarrow G) \\
&(\neg M \vee I) \wedge (M \vee \neg I) \wedge ( M \vee L) \wedge ((I \vee L) \rightarrow H) \wedge (H \rightarrow G) \\
&(I \vee L) \wedge ((I \vee L) \rightarrow H) \wedge (H \rightarrow G) \\
&H \wedge G
\end{align*}

This confuses me even more:

First, how did they resolve $(\neg M \vee I) \wedge (M \vee \neg I) \wedge ( M \vee L)$ to $(I \vee L)$? 
If we put together $(\neg M \vee I)$ and $( M \wedge L)$ we get $(I \vee L)$. Putting that together with $( M \vee \neg I)$ we get $(M \vee L)$.

Second, when we rewrite the forelast line and resolve we get

\begin{align*}
&(I \vee L) \wedge ((I \vee L) \rightarrow H) \wedge (H \rightarrow G) \\
&(I \vee L) \wedge ((\neg I \wedge \neg L) \vee H) \wedge (\neg H \vee G) \\
&(I \vee L) \wedge (\neg I \vee H) \wedge (\neg L \vee H) \wedge (\neg H \vee G) \\
&(H \vee L) \wedge (\neg L \vee G) \\
&H \vee G
\end{align*}

so not $H \wedge G$.. I'm confused. Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s true that *either ... or* often means *exclusive or*, but that is by no means always the case. Consider the following sentence:

> If John is either a veteran or over the age of 65, he is entitled to a discount at XYZ Market.

The normal reading of this sentence is that John is entitled as long as he meets at least one of the qualifications: he’s a veteran, or he’s over 65, or he’s a veteran who is over 65. This interpretation, with so-called *inclusive or*, is the normal reading of any sentence of this type. In particular, it’s the normal reading of this sentence:

> If the unicorn is either immortal or a mammal, then it is horned.

Thus, the symbolic translation is indeed $(I\lor L)\to H$.

You’re quite right in thinking that $(\neg M\lor I)\land(M\lor\neg I)\land(M\lor L)$ is not equivalent to $I\lor L$: the first expression is false when $M$ is false and $I$ is true, while the second is true. However, that’s not what the author is claiming: he’s claiming only that the first *implies* the second. And that is true: as you noted, $(\neg M\lor I)\land(M\lor L)$ gives you $I\lor L$, and it turns out that we simply don’t care that $M\lor\neg I$ is also true.

That takes us down to

$$(I\lor L)\land\big((I\lor L)\to H\big)\land(H\to G)\;.$$

The first two conjuncts then give us $H$, so we can deduce $H\land(H\to G)$, and from that we get $H\land G$.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian M Scott have brilliantly answered above, the trick of the solution is to note that

> $(¬M∨I)∧(M∨L) \Rightarrow I \vee L$

Recall that logical reasoning is all about *entailment*, and if certain sentence, say, $\alpha$, entails other, say, $\beta$, it does not follow that both sentences are logically equivalent, although it can happens to be the case if $\beta$ entails $\alpha$ as well.

It might be helpful to get a insight of the above assertion by noting that:

$$\begin{align} (¬M∨I)∧(M∨L) & \Rightarrow (¬M∧M)∨(I∧L) \tag{1} \\  
&\Rightarrow \bot \vee (I∧L)   \tag{2}  \\
&\Rightarrow I∧L   \tag{3}  \\
&\Rightarrow I∨L \tag{4}\\ \\
\end{align}$$

That is, we can distribute $¬M∨I$ over $M∨L$, eventually making some simplifications to get our desired result $I \wedge L$. Together with $((I∨L)→H)$ and $H \wedge G$ get $H$ and $G$ by modus ponens, respectively. Hence the document's answer:

$G \wedge H: \text{the unicorn is horned and magical}$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is easily solved from the text version.

1. If the unicorn is mythical, then it is immortal.
2. If the unicorn is not mythical, then it is a mortal mammal.
3. If the unicorn is either immortal or a mammal, then it is horned.
4. The unicorn is magical if it is horned.

From (1+2) it follows that the unicorn is either immortal or a mortal mammal. Therefore the if-condition in sentence (3) is true, which implies that the unicorn is horned. Sentence (4) then asserts that the unicorn is horned.

In conclusion: H is true and G is true.

Comment: Part of the OP's confusion is that he takes "either - or" to mean exclusive or.  Then the application of hypothesis 3 wouldn't work, because a mythical unicorn could be both immortal and a mammal.  So I'd add to your answer that the "either - or" in 3 (as in most mathematical contexts) is intended in the inclusive sense.

Comment: I was the first person to respond to the question at hand. I thought it would be useful to the OP to point out that if you skip the formal logic, and instead focus on the English text, it is straightforward to understand the final result. This also makes it easier to check the different steps in the formal logic. It find annoying that I get down-voted for my efforts.